# Mocking my Classes private service property

Tags: php, phpunit

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to figure  this out. I'm trying to mock a private service property, so that it's methods will not be called during testing.

I've been unable to find relevant solutions online.

```
class MyClass
{
  private $service

  public function __construct($service) {
    $this->service = $service;
  }

  public function myMethod()
  {
    $this->service->doStuff();
    ...do other stuff that I need to test...
  }
}
```

And in the test class, where I need to mock `$service`, to not call `doStuff()`

```
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class MyClassTest extends TestCase
{
  public function setup()
  {
   ...
  }

  public function testMyMethod()
  {
    $myClass = clone $this->app['MyClass'];

    // Need to mock doStuff() here, so it is not called. 
    $myClass->service = $this->mockDoStuff();

    //...test the other stuff in myMethod()...
  }
}
```

I've looked into RelfectionClasses, but I'm not sure that they can help me here.
I know changing `$service` to `public` would work, but that isn't an option unfortunately.
Thanks for the help guys, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The good news is that you're already using dependency injection. This allows you to use mock/stub objects easily. Please take a look at the documentation section regarding [stubbing](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/test-doubles.html#stubs). The general idea is that you override the object you don't want running with a "stub" in order to prevent its ordinary actions from occurring.

Something like the following should work:

```
class MyClassTest extends TestCase
{
  public function setup()
  {
   ...
  }

  public function testMyMethod()
  {
    // Method doStuff() will be overridden so that it does nothing and simply returns 'someValue'.
    $stub = $this->createMock(MyService::class);
    $stub->method('doStuff')->willReturn('someValue');
    $myClass = new MyClass($stub->getMock());
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, not sure this will work. It gives me the error: `Argument x passed to MyClass::__construct() must be an instance of Service, instance of Mock_Service_d8d9c331 given`

Comment: `$stub = $this->createMock(MyService::class)->setMethods(['doStuff'])->getMock();` would be correct here I guess.

Comment: Ah, right, my mistake. I forgot about that crucial step. I'll fix my answer. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: @imAnIdiot123 Please try the updated the solution. Sorry about that!